# It is possible to build when a change is pushed to BitBucket even when Jenkins is in localhost?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

It is possible to build when a change is pushed to BitBucket even when Jenkins is in **localhost**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Jenkins is in a localhost then it probably does not have a dedicated public IP address that you can use for the BitBucket webhook. By using [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.io) you can create a tunnel to your Jenkins localhost instance so that it can consume the BitBucket build webhook.

For example, if your Jenkins installation is at `localhost:8080` with ngrok installed you can call `ngrok http 8080` from the command line and it will give you a public url that will tunnel to your local Jenkins.

Add that ngrok url as the target url of the BitBucket webhook and you should be in business.

**NOTE:** I believe ngrok charges a small monthly fee for a static url.

Alternatively, [BitBucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) offers 50 minutes of free Jenkins builds each month to all free users and more time to paid users. (not sure it's actually Jenkins but it's similar)